# Same query in category.php and in function.php, but different result

Tags: ajax, query

What I wan to do is:
On the category page show the latest post 0 - 10 with category id 5. Then I have created a load more button which I call with ajax and there I want to show news from 11 - 20 with category id 5, and next time they clicks load more 21 - 30 and so on...

I have a problem with when i'm calling this:

```
$args = array(
    'suppress_filters' => true,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'cat' => 5,
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
```

The problem is that I get different results on the category.php site and on the function.php site (where I call a function with ajax)

I'm I missing something or doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer - the query on the category page had post_status = 'publish' by default and the query in the function.php had post_status = 'publish' OR post_status = 'future' OR post_status = 'draft' OR post_status = 'pending' as default, so the solution was to be more explicit in the $args and add 'post_status' => 'publish'.